# Rails - What is data-date option in datepicker

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

Can someone kindly explain what is data-date option in f.text_field used for?

I'm trying to understand the usage of datepicker and still not clearly understand what exactly the data-date option is.

```
<%= f.text_field :date_from, 'data-behaviour' => 'datepicker', 'data-date' => @inventory_schedule.date_from.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), :value=>@inventory_schedule.date_from.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')%>
```

Appreciate and Thanks in advance.

Comment: What Rails are you using? I didn't think Rails automatically gave you a date picker. My guess is you're using some third party JS, and it's looking for a data-date attribute, probably to set the default date. You can just play around with it and see how your datepicker reacts.

Comment: Thanks. It's jqueryUi datepicker.

Comment: I don't think the [jQuery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) uses data tags.

Comment: Thanks MrDanA. it seems nothing significantly noticeable if i add data-date or not. But it would better to find out what exactly it can be useful for. Anyway, thanks for your comment.

Comment: Rails and jQuery UI aren't using it, so it would probably be some other third party code. If you don't see it doing anything, then it probably isn't. But take stock of what else you have included, and then check to see if any of them care about it. Are you working on some production or legacy code? That data attribute could also be there for tests or something, for custom JS nothing to do with a datepicker, etc.

Comment: I'm working on production which take over from previous development team. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Thetnaung can you post your js code where your datepicker is called?

Comment: Hi Mandeep, here is the js $('[data-behaviour~=datepicker]').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', showButtonPanel: true, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });